# Не обновляются данные в MySQL по запросу UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql

Как исправить?

Из формы данные летят в обработчик. Но не обновляется информация в базе данных MYSQL по запросу UPDATE. Все работает отлично, без ошибок, вот только информация в базе не обновляется.  Код такой:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost", "topuser", "12345");
mysql_select_db("topyarus", $db);
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8');

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    if ($id == '') {
        unset($id);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['text'])) {
    $text = $_POST['text'];
    if ($text == '') {
        unset($text);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['meta_d'])) {
    $meta_d = $_POST['meta_d'];
    if ($meta_d == '') {
        unset($meta_d);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['meta_k'])) {
    $meta_k = $_POST['meta_k'];
    if ($meta_k == '') {
        unset($meta_k);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['title'])) {
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    if ($title == '') {
        unset($title);
    }
}
if (isset($_POST['test'])) {
    $test = $_POST['test'];
    if ($test == '') {
        unset($test);
    }
}
if (isset($test)) {
    $text = $test;
}

if (isset($text) && isset($meta_d) && isset($meta_k) && isset($title)) {
    $result_add = mysql_query("UPDATE settings SET text='$text', meta_d='$meta_d', meta_k='$meta_k', title='$title' WHERE id='$id'");

    if ($result_add == 'true') {
        echo "<p>Успешно добавлено в базу</p>";
    } else {
        echo "<p>Не добавлено в базу</p>";
        exit(mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    echo "<p>Вы заполнили не все поля!!!</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: ` == 'true'` это что еще такое?) И что пишет `mysql_error`?

ЗЫ: код вообще жестокий, по-нормальному он в 3 раза меньше

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Исправил, == 'true' код работает, скорее всего дело было в этом

Answer (score 0):

WHERE id='$id.'")  zdes posle $id to4ka zachem postavili?

Comment: Изменил, ...дело не в этом!

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так и у меня все работает, после этого кода стоит форма с action="эта страница.php", главное, чтобы метод GET был здесь и в форме, ну или POST.

```
<?php 
  if (isset($_GET["admin_login"])){
  $username = trim($_GET["admin_login"]);
  $password = trim($_GET["admin_password"]);
  $title = trim($_GET["site_title"]);
  $description = trim($_GET["site_description"]);
  $keywords = trim($_GET["site_keywords"]);
  if (($username != "") and ($password != "") and ($title != "") and ($description !=  "") and ($keywords != "")) {
   mysql_query("UPDATE `setting` SET username='$username', password='$password', title='$title', description='$description', keywords='$keywords'");
   $error = "<p><span>Настойки сохранены !</span></p>";
}
 else 
  $error = "<p><a>Заполните все поля !</a></p>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

А слово **COMMIT** вам о чем то говорит?

Comment: Команды управления транзакциями и блокировками в MySQL!...
С ними плохо знаком! 

Как поступить?

Comment: @SoftR, у mysql по умолчанию AUTOCOMMIT=1, запрос=транзакция. Тут наоборот чтобы его вырубить, колдовать надо долго)